# Why do Python NumPy/SciPy numerical eigenvectors act incorrect compared to MATLAB when there is at least one eigenvalue degenerate point?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, physics

For a physics problem, I numerically solve an eigenvalue equation with a square matrix (that is usually complex-valued, but is guaranteed to have real eigenvalues by construction). I have a 2D parameter space `(x,y)`, over which I solve this equation at every point.
Then I take the dot product of an eigenvector and the discretized time derivative of another eigenvector along a trajectory in `(x,y)`. For example, if my matrix is `4 x 4`, and I get eigenvectors `A, B, C, D` with eigenvalues `a, b, c, d`, I am talking about `(A).(dB/dt)` (which is usually complex-valued). Then I calculate its complex argument/angle.

As long as my `(x,y)` points are sufficiently close enough (i.e. 'continuous'), and as long as I know that the eigenvalues of each eigenfunction considered are unique at every point along the trajectory (i.e. `a =/= b` at for all `(x,y)` making the trajectory), I can expect this angle to be a continuous quantity as well, without any sharp jumps (as in the first figure). However, when using Numpy/Scipy it seems as if this 'continuous' quality is ruined by a degenerate/repeating eigenvalue **even if it is not on the trajectory**. That is, if my trajectory comprises `{(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4),(x5,y5)}`, with unique eigenvalues at each point (i.e. `a1 =/= b1, a2 =/= b2, ...`), it seems as if that `a9 = b9` at `(x9, y9)` causes trouble even if `(x9, y9)` is not on the trajectory considered.
I deduced this by changing my matrix so that the eigenvalues of each eigenfunction are unique at each point (i.e. I forced `a9 =/= b9`). Doing so gave me a 'continuous' angle. On the contrary, both cases are 'continuous' in MATLAB, as expected in theory.

It seems as if the issue is with the complex phases assigned to the numerical eigenfunctions. I used `np.unwrap` to delve into this more (last figure below), but it wasn't too fruitful.
I have spent weeks trying to understand why, to no avail. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Expected behavior of complex argument along a trajectory without any repeating eigenvalues (both Python and MATLAB shows this when eigenvalues are unique everywhere):
[image]

Observed behavior when using `numpy.linalg.eig` or  `scipy.linalg.eig`:
[image]

Observed behavior when using `numpy.linalg.eig` AND `np.unwrap` - there aren't supposed to be jumps:
[image]

Comment: Did you check where does this behaviour starts from? As in, do Matlab and numpy/scipy return the same eigenvectors and eigenvalues? Are the time derivatives the same? Are the dot products the same? etc...

Comment: @MatteoV To my understanding, MATLAB and Python will have different eigenvectors thanks to the arbitrary phase given by each program. The final quantity after the dot product should in general be different, but the trajectory should be smooth/continuous. So it’s hard to test everything else with actual data.